# Display Json data in laravel view with Joins

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve data from database to laravel blade view with join associate table.

in my case I have two tables called `interesting_courses` and `courses`. here some student can have many interesting courses. Therefore `courses_id` stored as `json array` in database as follows.

```
["1","11","15","16"]
```

but I need to join the courses table to get the associate course name as follows.

```
["Hospitality","Business Management","Auto Mobile","Health Care"]
```

Below is my controller

```
$intresting_courses = DB::table('intresting_courses')
                            ->join('courses','courses.id','=','intresting_courses.courses_id')
                            ->where('intresting_courses.youth_id',$id)
                            ->first();
```

How can I join the tables.

Comment: What have you tried? show us your controller

Comment: hi. I have updated my question

Comment: Are you sure you have correct database names in query? Because you have said you have database name `interesting_courses` and in query you are using `intresting_courses`.

Comment: yes. it is correct

Comment: So please update database name in question. It is misleading.

Comment: database name is `intresting_courses`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can join it in query natively.

**The solution is to write two queries**

```
select * from intresting_courses where youth_id = ? limit 1

select * from courses where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

that way you can get courses that student intresting.

#### Here the laravel code for thoses queries.

```
$intresting_courses = DB::table('intresting_courses')
                        ->where('intresting_courses.youth_id', $id)
                        ->first();

$courses = DB::table('courses')
             ->whereIn('id', json_decode($intresting_courses->courses_id))
             ->get();
```

Comment: i tried but its getting error called `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in line of `whereIn('id', $intresting_courses->courses_id)`

Comment: @user3263347 I've updated the code, put `->toArray()` after `->courses_id`
try again please .

Comment: again a error called `Call to a member function toArray() on string`

Comment: I tried `$courses_ids = json_decode($intresting_courses->course_id);


          $courses = DB::table('courses')
                    ->whereIn('id', $courses_ids)
                    ->get();` But I get only first course.

Comment: can you show me actual string inside your `courses_id` column

Comment: `["1","11","15","16"]`

Comment: Bro its working. I did a mistake. relevant id in array not found in course as result. thats why i got one courses. Anyway `json_decode` is working instead of `toArray()`. Thanks bro. edit your answer with it and i will accept the answer